# Error in <form> tag-Springs MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing a simple chat application in springs mvc but there is an error as

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/UserDetails.jsp at line 23

20: <c:out value="${chat.message}"/>
21: </c:forEach>
22: <form:form id="chat" modelAttribute="chatList" method="post" action="saveChat.html">
23: <form:input path="message"/>
24: <input type="submit" value="Send" />
25: </form:form>
26: <br>
```

and

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'message' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'message' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:665)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:657)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:147)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:409)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.UserDetails_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(UserDetails_jsp.java:250)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.UserDetails_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(UserDetails_jsp.java:215)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.UserDetails_jsp._jspService(UserDetails_jsp.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

My jsp file is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Being Java Guys | User Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="color: teal;font-size: 30px">Group Chat</div>
<br><br>
<c:url var="userChat" value="saveChat.html"/>

<c:forEach items="${chat}" var="chat">
<c:out value="${chat.username}:"/>
<c:out value="${chat.message}"/>
</c:forEach>
<form:form id="chat" modelAttribute="chatList" method="post" action="saveChat.html">
<form:input path="message"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form:form>
<br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And relevant controller code is

```
@RequestMapping("/saveChat")
    public ModelAndView saveChat(@ModelAttribute("chatList") Chat chat,BindingResult result){
        userService.addChat(chat);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userList");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/userList")
    public ModelAndView getUserList() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("chat", userService.getChat());
        return new ModelAndView("UserDetails", model);

    }
```

The error is on the form input tag for sure since when I comment it this then it works fine.But why is that and what is the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userList");
```

causes a 303 redirect status code to be sent as a response. As such, the model attributes added during that request, won't be available in the next request your browser makes.

Consider using [`RedirectAttributes`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) (flash attributes) instead.

Comment: Hi but you am I getting the second error?I am relatively new to this work so I am totally clueless regarding this.

Comment: @Nilesh The model attributes (which are added as request attributes) aren't available because you are in a different request. Because they aren't available, the `modelAttribute="chatList"` declaration fails and throws the exception.

Comment: Hi,I am sorry but RedirectAttributes is not working for me.Can you provide a small snippet for the same?

Comment: @Nilesh I'll help you of course, but I'd like to see what you've tried. The [javaodc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) for `RedirectAttributes` is pretty clear and also gives an example.

Comment: Hi,I am using Eclipse IDE and there I am unable to view the RedirectAttributes given there.Am i required to import some library?

Comment: @Nilesh They are contained in the `spring-webmvc` jar, version 3.1 and later.

Comment: I added a line redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("chat", chat) inside my saveChat requestmapping and importing that library worked but now I am getting notreadablepropertyexception.Its unable to readthe 'message' bean and indicating some mistake in the getter.It all compresses to <form> tag again.Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: When I changed the expression to <form:input path="${chat,message}"> then i get a NumberFormatException:For input string message

Comment: @Nilesh The path attribute expects the path to the object, not the value of an EL expression? Use `<form:input path="message"/>` if `chat` is the name of the model attribute in `form:form`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36614/discussion-between-nilesh-and-sotirios-delimanolis)